# Pandas / Datetime, year form variable

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using pandas to automatically clean a number of CSV files. 
The data looks like this

```
      date     value
1    13 Sep     9
2     5 Oct     8 
3    10 Oct     99
```

I use the following code to convert the string to datetime

```
pd.to_datetime(new_df[0].str.replace(' ', ''), format='%d%b')
```

(The replace is done to remove the extra spaces that sometimes occur)

This works fine - except for the fact that no year is supplied in the date and pandas gives it the year 1900 by default

```
       date     value
1    1900-09-13    9
2    1900-10-05    8 
3    1900-10-10    99
```

Luckily, I can fetch the year from the filename and have it standing by as the variable 'fileyear'. But I am unsure how to use it to set the correct date.

I tried something like:

```
pd.to_datetime(new_df[0].str.replace(' ', ''), format='%d%b' + '2016')
```

But that does not work. Does anyone know how to supply a (partially) known date to a datetimeformat?

Comment: Where there's no year it'll default to 1900 - so what you'll have to do is update it afterwards (maybe by adding 116/117 years to it?). Or, amend the text to include the correct year and then convert it to a datetime including the year... the best approach probably depends on how/where you can get the year from.

Comment: So maybe just `pd.to_datetime(new_df[0].str.replace(' ', '') + '2016', format='%d%b%Y')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the date format to include the year `%d%b%Y`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace(' ', '')  + '2016', format='%d%b%Y')

1   2016-09-13
2   2016-10-05
3   2016-10-10
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to remove space between two numbers then use `pd.to_datetime` i.e

```
df['clean_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('(?<=^\d).*(?=\d)', '') + ' 2016')

    date    value clean_date
1  1 3 Sep      9 2016-09-13
2    5 Oct      8 2016-10-05
3   10 Oct     99 2016-10-10
```